# Validate enum type with [#Assert\Choice]

Tags: php, symfony

I'm trying to validate enum type inside a custom DTO class. I'm trying to use the Symfony `#[Assert\Choice]` attribute but it seems that it doesn't work if I pass wrong value.

Custom DTO:

```
#[Assert\Choice(callback: 'getConditionTypes')]
public string $conditionType;

public static function getConditionTypes(): array
{
    return array_column(ConditionType::cases(), 'name');
}
```

Enum class:

```
enum ConditionType: string
{
    case NEW = "NEW";
    case USED = "USED";
    case CRASHED = "CRASHED";
    case BROKEN = "BROKEN";
    case FOR_PARTS = "FOR_PARTS";
}
```

When I try to pass a conditionType via Postman with a wrong value, for example  `"conditionType": "rand"` it passes through the DTO without any issue and I'm trying to catch if there is wrong value. What am I missing?

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Instead of providing a callback and using Assert\Choice, I used `#[Assert\Type(type: ConditionType::class)]` which automatically validates if the passed value is part of this enum.

Comment: This doesn't work if we want to validate a string against a backed enumeration.

Answer (score 0):

I used this approach:

1. Make a trait for my enums:

```
trait EnumDumperTrait
{
    public static function enumValues(): array
    {
        return array_map(static fn (BackedEnum $item): string|int => $item->value, self::cases());
    }

    public static function enumNames(): array
    {
        return array_map(static fn (BackedEnum $item): string => $item->name, self::cases());
    }
}
```

These functions useful not only in constraints.

2. Add trait to enum

```
enum AttributeKeyEnum: string
{
    use EnumDumperTrait;

    case TotalCost = 'total_cost';
    case UserId = 'user_id';
}
```

3. Use in constraint:

```
$assertions = new Constraints\Collection([
    // other constraints
    'key' => [
        new Constraints\Choice(choices: AttributeKeyEnum::enumValues()),
    ],
]);
```

4. Then call validation when I need it:

```
$validator->validate($data, $assertions)
```

$data is an arbitrary array, e.g. contents of API request.

Answer (score 0):

```
interface EnumValidate
{
    public static function validate(string $item): bool;
}

trait ValidateEnumTrait
{
    public static function validate(string $item): bool
    {
        if (!self::tryFrom($item) instanceof self) {
            throw new ValidatorException($item . ' is not a valid backing value for enum ' . self::class);
        }

        return true;
    }
}

enum MyEnum: string implements EnumValidate
{
    use ValidateEnumTrait;
...
```

In DTO

```
#[Assert\Callback([MyEnum::class, 'validate'])
```